# meteor-autoform examples all generate blank pages/no content

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

Good morning,

I've used aldeed's simple-schema and collection2 with no problems. What I wanted to to now is use the auto-form package ( https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#a-basic-insert-form ), more specifically one of the examples.

For simplicity purposes, I'm still trying to make the first example work:

autoform.html

```
    <head>
    <title>autoForm</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> insertBookForm}}
</body>

<template name="insertBookForm">
    {{> quickForm collection="Books" id="insertBookForm" type="insert"}}
</template>
```

common.js

```
    Books = new Mongo.Collection("books");
Books.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        label: "Title",
        max: 200
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        label: "Author"
    },
    copies: {
        type: Number,
        label: "Number of copies",
        min: 0
    },
    lastCheckedOut: {
        type: Date,
        label: "Last date this book was checked out",
        optional: true
    },
    summary: {
        type: String,
        label: "Brief summary",
        optional: true,
        max: 1000
    }
}));
```

The problem is that I always get a blank page. There's no error shown in the meteor app terminal.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, try adding meteor `add ongoworks:security` this should help you.